# Why does suspend not work (the computer turns right back on)?

Tags: windows-7, suspend

On a recent Windows 7 (fresh install), I cannot suspend the computer, as it will immediately turn right back on. I was able to suspend just fine running on XP. Also this is a desktop machine.

Comment: I had this issue on Vista as well. I thought it was a touchy keyboard or mouse (using a logitech wireless combo) but 7 doesn't have that problem on the same hardware.

Answer (score 2):

This was the same problem that I had before. If you have a laptop, change the power plan to Balanced not High performance because it interferes with standby.

Comment: If you run the Windows 7 troubleshooter and view the detailed report, it will say, "High Performance uses additional power and might prevent the computer from entering sleep mode."

Comment: Hm, still no go.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help. Hope you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this on some laptops when they are not flat as the touchpad/pointer sometimes registers a move which will bring it out of standby.... Alternatively as @Rob Allen said in the comment, it can be a dodgy keyboard or mouse.

I would recommend that if you are happy just using the power button, take a look in `Device Manager` and for your keyboard/mice, go in to the power management tab and uncheck `Allow this device to wake the computer`.

[image]

If you are still having problems, it could be that your BIOS is set to the wrong power management settings, try and see if there is an option to enable standby.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem.